# How to change path of Qt fonts when using static Qt app?

Tags: linux, qt, path, embedded

I'm trying to run the static Qt demo on my embedded Linux via NFS by executing: 
./deform -qws (running on Qt-enterprise-4.8) as my static Qt demo is residing on my host Ubuntu PC.

However I received the following error:

QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm/lib/fonts - is Qt installed  correctly?

is there a way to change PATH of QFontDatabase for my embedded Linux to look for it in another PATH residing on my Ubuntu PC?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a Qt application I compiled myself (sqlitebrowser):

```
QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /unibas/lcs-software/software/Qt5/5.9.3-goolf-1.7.20/lib/fonts.
Note that Qt no longer ships fonts. Deploy some (from http://dejavu-fonts.org for example) or switch to fontconfig.
```

I was able to get it work by pointing the `QT_QPA_FONTDIR` environment variable to a folder containing Type1 fonts. I used the following command:

```
QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/ sqlitebrowser
```

In your case the command could look like:

```
QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/  ./deform -qws
```